# Two fields on CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid

I want to use Sendgrid in order to send two emails at the same time. The code below works for a single email. I would like to send the second one without repeating all this code. Is it possible to do it, perhaps by appending another value to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, which is the only field that changes?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"personalizations\": [\n    {\n      \"to\": [\n        {\n          \"email\": \"you@example.com\"\n        }\n      ],\n      \"subject\": \"Test\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"from\": {\n    \"email\": \"me@example.com\"\n  },\n  \"content\": [\n    {\n      \"type\": \"text/html\",\n      \"value\": \"Hello world!"\n    }\n  ]\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer SG.1234123412341234",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L22 In other words, yes, send multiple personalizations (break that json out into an array and add a second to the array for the second email and so on, then re-json encode it for the api call).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add multiple "to" objects in personalisation json. 
Like below -

```
"to":["email":"abc@abc.com"],"to":["email":"abc2@abc2.com"] ....
```

Comment: In this case it would be sending a different email content to a different recipient. I tried adding a new "personalization" object in the JSON but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what happens when you use new object? does it send to only first email ?